# How to use the `:` function statement in this code?

Tags: lua

```
NE = {
    Functions = {
        test = function (x)
            print(x)
        end
    },
    Commands = {
        command = function(self)
            self.Functions.test("x") 
        end
    }
}

NE.Commands.command(NE)
```

In this part of the code:

```
NE.Commands.command(NE)
```

How can I use the `:` function statement ?

I tried using

```
NE:Commands.command(NE)
```

or

```
NE.Commands:command(NE)
```

but is not working

Comment: Can you remove `Commands` subtable to simply write `NE:command()` ?

Comment: Why do you want to use a colon? Do you need access to `Commands`?

Answer (score 1):

You should realize that `xxx:func(...)` is just a syntax sugar. It equals to `xxx.func(xxx, ...)`.

In your question, `NE.Commands:command(NE)` will behave as `NE.Commands.command(NE.Commands, NE)`, that's why it doesn't work.

In my opinion, you need to rewrite your code to use ':' for calling a function. There has no way to make `NE.Commands:command(NE)` works.

See also Lua manual: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.10

Comment: `There has no way to make NE.Commands:command(NE) works.` I don't recommend it but metatables would work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to write it as

```
NE.Commands:command(NE)
```

You could change it to

```
NE = {
    Functions = {
        test = function (x)
            print(x)
        end
    },
    Commands = {
        command = function(_, self)
            self.Functions.test("x") 
        end
    }
}
```

Your other suggestion of

```
NE:Commands.command(NE)
```

can never work because `Commands` is not a function

Comment: But it shouldn't work only with NE.Commands:command() ? because of the `:`

Comment: I made it work like that:
```
NE = {
    Functions = {
        test = function (x)
            print(x)
        end
    },
    command = function(self)
        self.Functions.test("x") 
    end
    -- Commands = {
    --     command = function(_, self)
    --         self.Functions.test("x") 
    --     end
    -- }
}

NE:command()
```

But how can I make it work if the function is in a table ?